# Regex compare strings from multiple files

Tags: regex, linux, scripting, sed, awk

I have multiple XML files that contain various strings. I also have a text file of strings, some of which are contained within the XML files.

XML:

```
text="$$sRegister $$s is stuck at One. (VDB-5014)" uid="5014"/>
```

String File:

```
is stuck at one
```

I would like to print the strings that are both in my string file and my XML file. This way I can set the correct message type in the XML file. Given the high volume of messages I've been attempting to automate this process. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grep -f`:

```
grep -f stringFile xmlFile
```

Comment: I was waiting for the timer to count down, it wouldn't let me accept it early. Thanks all.

Comment: Appreciate it. Cheers